# how to invoke dynamically any js function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

A web page is runing at client side and there is  `div` in the page which dynamically changes it's innerHTML via `ajax fn()` but i get issue with `jQuery fn()` which is not running.

suppose this is the running web page

```
<html> <head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.2.min.js"> </script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui.min.1.8.11.js"> </script>
</head> <body>
    <div id = "dynamic"> </div>
    <input type = "button" id="click" />

 <script type="text/javascript">

   $("#click").click(function(){
        // send request to server via ajax (xmlHttprequest )
        // get html contents as responseText 

    $("#dynamic").html(responseText);
       });
 </script>    
</body>  </html>
```

As you can see above in the given example, if client clicks on button, a request sent to server and gets innerHTML as responseText which is put into `dynamic div`.

***responseText as innerHTML working : *** `css` properties are loaded and working

```
<div id="myDiv"> </div>
<style type="text/css">
  #myDiv { width: 100%; height:100%; background: blue; }
</style>
```

**innerHTML isn't working :** `css` properties isn't working if i use jQuery to load the css file

```
<div id="myDiv"> </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $("head").append($("<link rel='stylesheet' href='test.css' type='text/css' />"));
       });
</script>
```

and the `test.css` is at server (the css properties is defined in external files to)

```
#myDiv { width: 100%; height:100%; background: blue; }
```

Comment: Are you asking how to dynamically include a CSS style-sheet?

Comment: i know how to include but only in this case the css file isn't loading.

Comment: Your code is missing the crucial part of actually performing the ajax call. Could you include it (possibly the culprit here)

Comment: ajax call is successful and i get the responseText. even innerHTML works better when i embeded the css properties including with html contents. only the problem is, loading the external css file when changes the `innerHTML`.

Answer (score 0):

if the function lives in the global space

```
window["functionName"]();
```

If you've namespaced, then

```
myNameSpace["functionName"]();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to dynamically add a style-sheet to the DOM then try this:

```
$.get('test.css', function(responseCSS)
{
   $('<style type="text/css"></style>').html(responseCSS).appendTo("head");
});
```